# GeoPandas GeoDataFrame polygon geometry - calculate area

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas

I have a geopandas GeoDataFrame with Polygon geometry and I am calculating the area of the polygon, however, I am not sure what the unit is for the area.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

 # create two dummy polygons
 poly1 = Polygon([(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)])
 poly2 = Polygon([(1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (1,2)])

 # create a geopandas DataFrame with two rows
 data = {'name': ['Polygon 1', 'Polygon 2'], 'geometry': [poly1, poly2]}
 df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, crs='EPSG:4326')
```

I'd like to reproject the geometry and calculate the area in square meters or another linear unit, however, I have been having issues with re-projection and transforming geometries:

```
 `df['geometry'][0].area`
```

when I attempt to convert the `crs` to a `projected coordinate reference` system, I get `Polygon (Inf Inf....)`.

```
df.to_crs('EPSG:32610', inplace=True)
df.crs
```

Expected output is to calculate the `area()` in `square meters` units.

Comment: I wonder if there is something wrong with your environment, as your code just works fine for me... I'd try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
import geopandas as gpd

poly1 = Polygon([(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)])
poly2 = Polygon([(1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (1,2)])

data = {'name': ['Polygon 1', 'Polygon 2'], 'geometry': [poly1, poly2]}
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, crs='EPSG:4326')

df_proj = df.to_crs('EPSG:32610')

df_proj['area_m2'] = df_proj['geometry'].area

print(df_proj[['name', 'area_m2']])
```

which gives you

```
        name       area_m2
0  Polygon 1  4.099949e+10
1  Polygon 2  3.882300e+10
```